# java webservice jax-ws when is @webmethod required

Tags: web-services

I am trying to understand `JAX-WS` and am having a difficult time to understand the purpose of `@WebMethod` Annotation.

Here is sample code:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT)
public  class TestServiceImpl  {

  public String greet1(String msg) {
    return "greet1";
  }

  @WebMethod
  public String greet3(String msg) {
    return "greet3";
  }

  public String greet5(String msg) {
    return "greet5";
  }
```

}

when I am looking at the `WSDL` I can see all the 3 methods `'greet1'` and `'greet3'` do not have `@WebMethod` annotation . 
     Only '`greet2'` has the annotation.

Here is the `WSDL`:

```
<binding name="TestServiceImplPortBinding" type="tns:TestServiceImpl">   
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"  
 style="document"/>
<operation name="greet5"></operation>
<operation name="greet3"></operation>
<operation name="greet1"></operation>
</binding>
```

So not sure what is the use of WebMethod annotation ?

Comment: Which WS engine do you use?

Comment: I am right now directly generating it using JDK 1.8 but in future my plan is to use Apache CXF . which do you use ? what would you recommend ?

Comment: I guess that the reference implementation of JAX-WS for Java 8 is Metro - https://javaee.github.io/metro/ , I mostly use it for testing purposes, my preffered JAX-WS implementation is Apache CXF.

Answer (score 0):

The `@WebMethod` annotation is used internally by web service engines to expose any public method as a web service operation. As it said in JEE specification:

> @WebMethod specifies that the method is exposed as a public operation of the Web
>   Service. You must explicitly use this annotation to expose a method;
>
> if you do not specify this annotation, the method by default is not
>   exposed.

But, as it comes from my practice, some application servers (e. g. IBM WebSphere and thus some WS engines) expose your method as a web service operation even if you haven't put such annotation prior to a method signature. I guess it varies depends on JAX-WS implementation.

It means any `public` method in a class annotated with a `@WebService` annotation will be exposed as a web service operation. To avoid such behavior you should explicitly annotate a method with `@WebMethod(exclude=true)`.